# "Change of variables" in $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x+t)$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

Let $f:(0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a real-valued function, such that for some $t,C>0$,
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x+t)\leq C
\end{equation}
Is it also true that $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)\leq C$? Particularly, is it true that $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x+t)=\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recall that

$$
\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L
$$

if and only if the following two conditions hold:

1. For every sequence $x_n \to \infty$, we have $\limsup_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) \leq L$.
2. There exists a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \limsup_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)= L$.

---

We first show that $\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) \leq \limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x+t)$.

Fix a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ satisfying condition (2) such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = \limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x)$, and let $y_n = x_n - t$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n + t) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n)$, so by condition (1), the inequality
$$
\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) \leq \limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x+t) \tag{a}
$$
holds.

We next show that $\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x+t) \leq \limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x)$.

Fix a sequence $x_n \to \infty$ satisfying condition (2) such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n + t) = \limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x+t)$, and let $y_n = x_n + t$. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(y_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n+t)$, so by condition (1), the inequality
$$
\limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x+t) \leq \limsup_{x \to \infty} f(x) \tag{b}
$$
holds.

Combining (a) and (b) gives the desired equality.

Comment: Many thanks! Do you know of a reference for the definition of $\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ you use?

Comment: Rockafellar and Wets, *Variational Analysis* (1998), Lemma 1.7 states that $\liminf_{x \to \bar x} f(x) = \min \{ \alpha \in [-\infty, \infty] : \exists x_n \to x \text{ with } f(x_n) \to \alpha \}$, which can be unpacked into my version. The equivalent formula for $\limsup_{x \to \bar x} f(x)$ is found on page 13.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to prove straight from the definition of $\limsup$. By definition,
$$\limsup_{x \to \infty}f(x + t) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\sup_{y > x}f(y + t).$$
Thus
$$\limsup_{x \to \infty}f(x + t) = \lim_{x \to \infty}\sup_{y > x + t}f(y).$$
Now by a standard $\varepsilon$ argument for $\lim$ (probably what you call "change of variables"), we get
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\sup_{y > x + t}f(y) = \lim_{z \to \infty}\sup_{y > z}f(y),$$
and this is exactly $\limsup_{z \to \infty}f(z)$.